# Mapped drive disconnects after inactivity

Tags: windows

I've got scripts that run nightly that need access to a mapped drive.  I would like to avoid having the script manually map the drive as I don't want to have to dump my credentials into it.

The problem is with the drive mapped as it is, by the time the scripts run, the mapped drive can't be found.  I've got the server configured to never go to sleep and net config server autodisconnect is set to -1.  This is on win server 2008r2

Can anyone help me figure out a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the power managment options for your ethernet cards and or adapters to make sure they are set for performance mode or never to allow for power save modes